# Any object can be assigned in interface reference variable when class will implement these interface

Tags: java

Any object can be assigned in interface reference variable when class will implement these interface.

```
public interface MyInterface {
}

public class Test implements MyInterface {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        MyInterface myInterface = test;
    }
```

What is the meaning of this line?

```
MyInterface myInterface = test;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A variable has two types: a declared (or static) type and a run time type.

The variable

```
Test test = new Test();
```

is declared as type `Test` and the object it references is of run time type `Test`.

This variable

```
MyInterface myInterface = test;
```

is declared as type `MyInterface` and the object it references is of type `Test`.

Nothing actually happens to the object when you assign a reference to it to a variable of some super type. You will only be able to invoke methods visible to that declared type on the variable.

---

Let's try to draw it

```
   Reference               Object                     Reference
    (Test)                 (Test)                   (MyInterface)
     test  -----------> actual object  <-----------  myInterface
```

Comment: Thanks Sotirios,But I am not able to understand it.

Comment: @Arun Does the drawing help?

Comment: Thanks, Now i am able to understand.In your comment "some super type" what is meaning.In java what will be said this process.

Comment: @Arun Because `Test` implements `MyInterface`, `MyInterface` is said to be a super (or parent) type of `Test`.

Comment: Normally when extend any class then we can assign object of sub class to super class like A a = new B(); when class B extend A.Here is interface (Is it same for ineterface because Interface used as "Type")

Answer (score 4):

`Interface` is used as `Type`. This is one of the advantage of using `Interface`. Thus we can have a Type variable of `Interface` which can refer to any implementation which `implements` this `Interface`.

Best example to understand is Any `Collection` Interface.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

In above example `List` is interface which variable is points to `ArrayList` which implements List `interface`. Say in future you want to change `ArrayList` to `LinkedList`, then you have to change only one word that is `ArrayList` to `LinkedList`. So it will look like

```
List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
```

And one more benefit is that *Loose Coupling*.

Answer (score 0):

Reference test referring to Test class object is assigned to implemented interface MyInterface